# Inline div not wrapping correctly

Tags: css, inline

I have a series of inline divs that aren't wrapping correctly. As the browser is resized, the divs should be aligning flush left but sometimes they are flush right. I've read several articles on this but they don't seem to be the same issue. Any help would be much appreciated. My jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/7uuLaLg4/.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .box
    {
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .address .item
    {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
    }
</style>



<div class="box">
    <div class="address">
        <div class="item">
            <div>Address (Number & Road) <label class="required">*</label></div>
            <div><input id="User_Address_Address1" name="User.Address.Address1" style="width: 13em;" type="text" value="1 Main St." /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div>Address 2 (APT, Suite...)</div>
            <div><input id="User_Address_Address2" name="User.Address.Address2" type="text" value="" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div>City<label class="required">*</label></div>
            <div><input id="User_Address_City" name="User.Address.City" type="text" value="Anytown" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div>State<label class="required">*</label></div>
            <div>
                <select id="User_Address_StateID" name="User.Address.StateID">
                    <option selected="selected" value="3">Kentucky</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div>Zip<label class="required">*</label></div>
            <div><input class="zip-mask" id="User_Address_Zip" maxlength="5" name="User.Address.Zip" style="width: 5em;" type="text" value="12345" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div>County<label class="required">*</label></div>
            <div>
                <select id="User_Address_CountyID" name="User.Address.CountyID">
                    <option value="0"></option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="125542">Campbell</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div>Country<label class="required">*</label></div>
            <div>
                <select id="User_Address_CountryID" name="User.Address.CountryID">
                    <option value="0"></option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="1">United States</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is fixed example.

http://jsfiddle.net/7uuLaLg4/2/

```
.box{
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
}

.address .item{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not all the same height which is why sometimes they act like they are floating right.

Something like `min-height: 60px;` should help.

```
.address .item {
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 60px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bb1ooguo/1/

Comment: when you put display: inline or inline-block after that you don't need float left.

Comment: Thanks I have amended my answer.